# html:default text display in a textbox

Tags: html

I`m dynamically building a form with few labels and textboxes within a for loop in classic asp,

code:

```
<td>
<input type="text"" name="<%=xtinct.item(i).getAttribute("col1")%>"/>
</td>
```

I need to put default text that should hide on onfocus.I can`t use "PlaceHolder" attribute.
HOw can I do it here???Please suggest some answers.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/UQe3r/ - doesn't work on all browsers though.

Comment: @yogi:No sir.I need to use only javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use placeholder

```
<input type="text"" name="<%=xtinct.item(i).getAttribute("col1")%>" placeholder="default text" />
```

you need to use some jQuery for IE. Read this post -

http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2012/02/html5-placeholder-in-ie7-and-ie8-fixed.html

**Edit:**

This will work on all browsers -

```
<input type="text" value="Your email" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='Your email'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your email') {this.value=''}">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NHzGu/)

Comment: @user1495475 read this for IE http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2012/02/html5-placeholder-in-ie7-and-ie8-fixed.html

Comment: Dipaks:Thanks for the answer.It works.Could you please tell me how to change text-color here???like blur.

Comment: @user1495475 Here check this post - http://kuttler.eu/post/html-forms-and-onclick-onfocus/ and if you talking about CSS then input[type="text"]{ color: red; }

Comment: :Thanks a lot.I got a problem here. when I put value="text",I`m getting two results,like one of "value",and other one of actual value entered in textbox. Please suggest an answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 placeholder attribute:

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Or you could use JavaScript. jQuery would be pretty easy to wire up. There's plenty of tutorials. Google 'default input field text with jQuery'.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<form name="f">
    <textarea name="<%=xtinct.item(i).getAttribute("col1")%>" onFocus="this.value=''">
        Enter your text here...
    </textarea>
</form>
```